# Arduino/C++ right way to use pointers

Tags: c++, arduino, esp8266, arduino-esp8266

I have the following scenario in a program that was written in C ++ (Arduino):

Service.h

```
class Service
{
 public:
   Service(AsyncWebServer *server, FS *fs);
   ~Service();

   void loop();

 private:
   AsyncWebServer *_server;
   FS *_fs;

   JsonObject *Settings;
   void LoadSettings();
}
```

Service.cpp

```
Service::Service(AsyncWebServer *server, FS *fs) : _server(server), _fs(fs) { }

Service::LoadSettings(){
{
  File configFile = _fs->open("data.json", "r");
  DynamicJsonBuffer jsonBuffer;
  JsonObject &root = jsonBuffer.parseObject(configFile);
  Settings = &root;
  configFile.close();
}

Service:loop() {
    LoadSettings();
}
```

In a correct program, once the **Settings** property is set, it should hold the value throughout the lifecycle, however I need to call the LoadSettings() method all the time because the **Settings** property is losing the value when the program exits the method LoadSettings()

What is the right way to work with pointers and class properties? What do i need to do?

Comment: Are you confusing pointers, the address of (`&`) operator and reference variables?

Comment: The `Settings` variable seems to be a pointer to data that will cease to exist once the `LoadSettings` function ends and the `jsonBuffer` object gets destructed.

Comment: That is the point, what do i need to change to value persists?

Comment: Don't use pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing what you are doing is creating a local object by parsing the object file and then leaving the function

```
DynamicJsonBuffer jsonBuffer; // declared locally
JsonObject& root = jsonBuffer.parseObject(configFile) // root local
```

creates root, a local reference, then you set Settings to point to address of that reference after leaving the function, `jsonBuffer` ceases to exist.

You should instead either declare jsonBuffer static or better, make it a member variable `_jsonBuffer`

Not sure why you need `root`, just write

```
Settings = &(_jsonBuffer.parseObject(configFile));
```

(maybe you should also rename `Settings` to `_settings` to have the same style as the other member variables).